# Ecosia as Default Search Engine in Opera

Tags: search, default, search-engine, opera, tampermonkey

Opera doesn't let you set [**Ecosia**](https://www.ecosia.org/) as the default search engine.
I'm a beginner. The workaround below is simple, but I'm posting it so that other beginners can use it as-is.
Just trying to help.

**Steps:**
1) Go to Opera settings, scroll down to "Search engine".
　　　Set DuckDuckGo.com as your default search engine.

2) Install the [**TamperMonkey**](https://addons.opera.com/en-gb/extensions/details/tampermonkey-beta/) extension.
　　　This allows you to automatically add JavaScript to pages you browse.

3) Enter the following code into **TamperMonkey**
　　　**NOTE: NEVER** use scripts from an unknown source.
　　　This is just a one-line redirect, posting the script here so anyone can review it.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Ecosia Default Search Engine in Opera
// @version      1.01
// @description  Sets Ecosia as default search engine by automatically redirecting you
//               when you search in DuckDuckGo.
// @author       Hagbard Hednig
// @match        http*://*duckduckgo.com/*?*q=*
// @namespace http://tampermonkey.net/
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    location.href=('https://www.ecosia.org/search?'+window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf('q='),window.location.href.length));
})();
```

No errors, no permissions required.
**Just posting the solution to help other beginners.**

Comment: Remark: you need to enable the option "Allow access to search page results" in `opera://extensions` otherwise tampermonkey won't be able to redirect you.
It did take me some time to figure this one out :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
// @match        http*://*duckduckgo.com/*?*q=*
```

this is row which define on which address script runs. So paste there your serach, like Google. Or only search something witch old searchengine and look if tampermonkey icon have red 1. If yes, script runs. If not, your address in row @match is bad.